# как добавить атрибуты элементов в массив

Tags: javascript, функции, foreach, while

у меня на странице есть 3 элемента с атрибутом data
С помощью forEach я их перебираю, добавляю onclick и функцию.
С помощью функции мне нужно добавлять data, по которому кликнули в массив.
Код рабочий, но по клику добавляется элемент не по очередно, а все сразу

```
function t5() {

    let tasks = document.querySelectorAll(".task-5")

    let count = 0

    while (count < tasks.length){
        let v = tasks[count].getAttribute("data")
        a5_res.push(v)
        count++
    }
     console.log(a5_res)

}
document.querySelectorAll('.task-5').forEach(elem => {
     elem.onclick = t5;
})
```

Comment: если вам надо добавлять только кликнутый, то зачем вы внутри функции опять выбираете все элементы и в цикле их суммируете? у события клика есть параметр - event, который передается в функцию. Вот добавьте этот параметр в функцию, и event.target будет описывать кликнутый элемент. у него и возьмете атрибут свой, который в свою очередь лучше назвать `data-value`, и обращаться к нему через `event.target.dataset.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ваша функция должна обрабатывать только кликнутый элемент, который можно получить через параметр-событие. Вы же почему то обрабатываете все элементы.

```js
var res = [];

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(elem => {
     elem.onclick = function(e){
        res.push(e.target.dataset.value); 
        console.log(res);
      };
})
```

```html
<button data-value="1">1</button>
<button data-value="2">2</button>
<button data-value="3">3</button>
<button data-value="4">4</button>
```